Cometí un error al tratar de montar /home en un disco externo en Fedora Linux
Hace más de una semana que estoy intentando usar un disco externo para montar allí /home en mi laptop.
Los pasos que seguí fueron:

formatear el disco y montarlo en    /mnt/carpeta

'''sudo cp -rf /home /mnt/carpeta'''

intenté renombrar /home a /home1 pero no pude porque estaba en uso

entré en el modo de mantenimiento a renombrarlo desde ahí

'''mv /home /home1'''

(lo que creo que fué un error) use nano para cambiar /etc/fstab para que use /home1 (que es el home original) porque quería saber si seguía booteando (booteó pero creo que borró todo lo de home1, así que el único backup que me queda ahora es lo que quedó en el disco al que quiero comvertir en mi nuevo home)(esto tampoco era muy grave porque seguía teniendo lo del disco intacto y esto era solo a modo de backup)

monté el disco en un nuevo directorio llamado /home

cambié fstab para que bootee con mi nuevo /home (lo que está en el disco, que copié en el paso 2, que es una copia de lo que tenía home original)

guardo y reinicio...


Cuando reinicié, al principio pareció iniciar, pero antes de entrar a la pantalla en la que ingreso mi contraseña, empezó a tirar errores diciendo que no se podían leer distintos archivos y configuraciones.
Detalles importantes:
*Cuando hice el paso 2 tuve que usar '''chown''' para que mi usuario se pueda acceder porque sino solo podía ser accedido por sudo.
*Esta serie de pasos no son las únicas cosas que hice, fué un proceso de prueba y error, pero no creo que hayan más cosas relevantes
*Mi OS es Nobara (es fedora con unos pocos cambios)
*Soy muy nuevo en linux (un mes de uso), aunque me manejo con mucha comodidad con la terminal.
No intenté solucionarlo de momento porque no quiero terminar dañando lo que está en el disco, con todos mis archivos. Pronto haré un backup y desde allí intentaré resolverlo.
Mi teoría es que al realizar el paso 2 por alguna razón no se copiaron los permisos y quedaron mal configurados.
Si alguien sabe que salió mal y/o como arreglarlo, agradezco infinitamente la ayuda.
Pregunten lo que necesiten. Gracias.
Edit: luego de investigar, me doy cuenta que en el paso 2 no iba -rf, sino -rp, estube siguiendo un tutorial y se vé que me confundí mientras borraba otras cosas.

Problema resuelto.
Mi error:
Como dije en el edit, el problema es que escribí así:
sudo cp -rf /home /mnt/carpeta

cp: copiar
-r: (se necesita para poder copiar directorios)
-f: no hace nada (acá me equivoqué)*
/home (primer parametro): cosa que copio
/mnt/carpeta (segundo parametro): lugar adonde lo copio
En vez de -f debí haber escrito -p, para mantener los permisos de escritura, lectura y ejecucion.
Cómo lo resolví:
Teniendo en cuenta que al iniciar el os todos los errores que me aparecian eran de archivos de configuración en el directorio .config, lo que hize fué ejecutar este comando:
sudo chmod -R 777 ~/.config

chmod: cambiar permisos de lectura, escritura y ejecucion
-R (mayúscula): (se necesita para poder hacerlo en un directorio)
777: (el numero 7 representa que x tiene el permiso de ejecutarlo, de leerlo y de escribirlo, el primer 7 es el sistema, el segundo 7 es un usuario y el terer 7 es un grupo)
~/.config: /home/(mi usuario)/.config
De todas formas esta solucion no es muy elegante porque 777 es un permiso demasiado poderoso, pero me funcionó para resolver el problema, investigaré para ver cómo dejarlo mejor configurado.
Por el momento solo cambié .config, pero es muy probable que tenga que cambiarle los permisos a muchos otros directorios y archivos.
Conclusiones:
LEAN LO QUE ESCRIBEN EN LA TERMINAL, es muy divertida de usar, pero presten atención a lo que hacen.
Edit:
Recomiendo darle permisos 777 a la mayoría de las .dotfiles (directorios que empiezan con .) ya que muchas tienen configuraciones importantes (configuraciones del DE, gestor de archivos, apps, etc).
